# ng serve error when adding a new SCSS style within Angular application

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I've create a brand new angular application using the CLI.

I selected SCSS as the stylesheet choice.

I type ng serve to run the application.

Everything is OK at this point.

I open the stylesheet and add any style

e.g.

```
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

The website now fails to build and I have the following error in the console window:

> Error: ./src/app/pages/myMod.module.ts Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
> NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)
> Error: Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): SassError: expected "{".    ╷
> 12 │   body

If I quit the ng serve and start it again it works.

But it'll fail as soon as I add a new css rule.

This is the latest version of node js and the CLI is also up to date.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the version of the cli? I know you said up-to-date but just double-checking

Comment: @eko Added the cli version

Comment: There's still an open issue, so i think they're working on it: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19892. I'd suggest you to downgrade atm tbh

Answer (score 0):

It might be several things:

-Do you use the hmr (Hot Module Replacement) to recompile the project each time you change it, you might configure it in your environnement then launch it with :

```
ng serve --hmr
```

(Documentation here :https://angular.io/cli/serve)

- Your SCSS might be ignored when the project is recompiling (through ng serve  live reload), you might check why.
- How is your SCSS imported? Is it part of a component? Is it declared or imported in a more global way (Through **angular.json** for example)